# How to get Scrollableview child elements values I am giving sample get when even listener performed?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am facing this problem how to get the values of child elements any one please help me I am  sharing my code in below. I have a `scrollableView` and on its `scrollend` **eventListener** I would like to get the **ImageViewID**.

```
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({

});

var data=[];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var view = Ti.UI.createView({

    });

    var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({

    });

    var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image:i+".png",
        imageId:i,
    });

    scrollView.add(imageView);
    view.add(scrollView);
    data.push(view);
}

scrollableView.add(data);

scrollableView.addEventListener('scrollend',function(e){
    /*I will get the imageView Id and image value how any one reply me I am not getting  */
    Ti.API.info('e.source.imageId'+e.source.imageId);/* I tried but it's not working*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the `imageId` by using the following code :

```
scrollableView.addEventListener('scrollend',function(e){
    /*I will get the imageView Id and image value how any one reply me I am not getting  */
    Ti.API.info('imageId' + e.view.children[0].children[0].imageId); /* I tried but it's not working*/
});
```

## EDIT

What happens above can be bifurcated as below :

1. `e.view` => Is the first `View` in the `for` loop

   ```
   var view = Ti.UI.createView({
   });
   ```
2. `children[0]` => Is the `scrollView` in the view above.

   ```
   var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
   });
   ```
3. `children[0].imageId` => Is the `ImageView` and now we can access all
   the properties of this element.

   ```
   var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
           image:i+".png",
           imageId:i,
   });
   ```

**Good Luck, Cheers**

**Ashish Sebastian**

Comment: Hi A.A.Sebastian thank you for helping me but what you suggesting that one is not working

Comment: @MRChowdary : is it giving any error? because I have given you a working code. Let me know what you get on scrollend. If the structure is the same what you have given in the question then it should definitely work. Or if you have changed the index of the image in the view then it should be accessed accordingly.